# How many numbers are required to make the returned values equal to integer N?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, python-2.7

Need to find smallest number P such that for given integer N

```
 sum of f(x)>=N. where f(x)=f(1)+f(2)+.....+f(p) where f(a) is number of times a number and then its quotient is divisible by 5 for example 100 is divisible by 5 two times as 100/5=20 and 20/5=4 but 4 is not divisible so f(100)=2
```

where function is defined as the the number of times the number and its quotient can be divided by 5.
For example for N=6 P would be 25 because 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24 are not divisible by 5 and 5 is divisible by 5 by only 1 so

```
f(5)=1,and same
f(10)=1,
f(15)=1,
f(20)=1
(20/5=4 but 4 is not divisible by 5) but 25 is divisible by 5
```

by two times since
     25/5=5 and 5/5 =1) so
     f(25)=2 so f(x)=f(1)+f(2)+.....f(25)=6

which is the answer so smallest P should be 25. Here is my code but i am having problem at some cases.

```
def myround(x, base=5):
    return ((base * round((x)/base)))

n=int(input())
count=0
i=5
while(n/i>=1):
    count+=1
    i=i*5
res=count+1
counter=0
for j in range(1,res+1):
    gcd_cal=((1/5)**j)
    counter+=gcd_cal
end_res=(n/counter)
zz=(myround(end_res))
reverse=zz-5
re=zz+5

counter1=0
for xx in range(1,res+1):
    div=int(5**xx)
    temp=(zz//div)
    counter1+=temp

counter2=0
for xx in range(1,res+1):
    div=int(5**xx)
    temp=(reverse//div)
    counter2+=temp

counter3=0
for xx in range(1,res+1):
    div=int(5**xx)
    temp=(re//div)
    counter3+=temp

if (counter1==n):
    print(zz)
elif(counter2==n):
    print(reverse)
elif(counter3==n):
    print(re)
else:
    print(max(zz,reverse,re))
```

Note:Recursion solution is too slow for large N say 10**9

PS:I want to find how many numbers are required to make the returned values equal to integer N say (6 as in example)

edit: DP solution to this problem can be

```
dict={}

def fa(x):
    if x in dict:
        return dict[x]
    if not x%5 and x%25 and x>0:  
        dict[x]=1
        return 1



    elif not x%5 and not x%25 and x>0:    
        dict[x]=1+fa(x//5)

        return 1+fa(x//5)
    else:
        return 0

def F(N):
    counter=0
    s=0 
    while s<N:

        counter+=5

        s+=fa(counter)
    return counter



for _ in range(int(input())):
    n=int(input())

    print(F(n))
```

Comment: What happens if `N=5`?

Comment: If n=5 f(5) will give 1,f(10) will give 1,f(15)=1,f(20)=1 and f(25) will give 2 so for n=5 i will have to take 25 because i want 1 count more  so the answer will be 25.

Comment: My DP solution works fine for N =math.pow(10,5) or less but for N >math.pow(10,5) it is slow.

Comment: You should fix indentation on the first example

Comment: indentation is fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that has constant storage and runs in time of order log(x). I cannot think that smaller storage or order of running time is possible.

The key idea is to treat `x` similar to a base-5 number. One way to find the base-5 representation of a number `n` is to find the first power of 5 that exceeds `n`, then keep decreasing that power of 5 and find how many of those fit into the number `n`. My routine is similar to that but removes the sums-of-exponents-of-5 rather than powers of 5. Finding the sum-of-exponents-of-n is easy for increasing powers of 5 due to a simple recurrence relation. There probably is a direct way to find the desired power of 5, but the second half of my function is slower than that so optimizing the first half of my function would not be much of an improvement.

I have tested this routine for values of `x` up to `10,000` and it checks. It is very fast, beyond `x=10**100`, though checking those results is very slow. Note that I prefer to use the parameter `n` for an integer value rather than your `x`.

Let me know if you need more explanation.

```
def smallestsumexp5s(n):
    """Return the smallest integer whose sum of the exponents of 5 in
    the prime decomposition of i for 1 <= i <= n is greater than or
    equal to n.
    """
    # Find the power of 5 whose sum passes n
    powerof5 = 5
    sumofexpsof5 = 1
    while sumofexpsof5 <= n:
        powerof5 *= 5
        sumofexpsof5 = sumofexpsof5 * 5 + 1
    # Cut off pieces of the target to find the desired integer
    remains = n
    result = 0
    while remains > 0:
        # Back off to the previous power of 5
        powerof5 //= 5
        sumofexpsof5 //= 5
        # Cut off pieces of the remaining number
        q, remains = divmod(remains, sumofexpsof5)
        # Adjust the accumulated result
        result += q * powerof5
    return result
```

Comment: sir,you are awesome!